# Wrong free size after extending volume in Windows 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I extended volume and now Explorer and Disk management shows correct size of volume, but did not add extended space as a free space.

Basically, I had 100Gb disk and had 30Gb free space, now I have 200Gb disk and still 30Gb of free space (numbers are same in Disk Management, Explorer and chkdsk.exe).

Screenshot of Disk Management below:

[image: DiskMan]

Comment: Could you post/link to a screenshot of Disk Manager, please?  I think I know what your problem is, but I'd need to see that to be sure.

Comment: Screenshot is here: [link](http://img13.imageshack.us/img13/2562/diskmanagerfrom20120831.png)

Comment: Glad I asked... that is not what I thought at all.  How odd.  Is it a VM?

Comment: Yes, it is a VMware VM. I extended partitions before on other servers (same 2008 R2) and did not have any issues. This is first time I hit a wall.

Answer (score -2):

Check that you're not limiting disk usage via quota properties of File Server Resource Manager.

Comment: That only affects the ability to use disk space, not to see the amount of free disk space.

Comment: Yep, I already checked it - all quotas are disabled (disk and folder quotas)